# How to display two columns vertically below each other in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid

Similar to how the Devexpress property [TcxGridBandedColumnPosition.RowIndex](https://docs.devexpress.com/VCL/cxGridBandedTableView.TcxGridBandedColumnPosition.RowIndex) works in DataGrid

Example from devexpress:

https://docs.devexpress.com/VCL/171164/ExpressQuantumGrid/task-based-help/banded-table-view
[image]

In the example, we have a band "Issue Info" and two columns located one below the other

As far as I understand there is only one way and that is to write custom renders if  it possible with current API.

Comment: You can possibly use this: [Column Grouping](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-groups/)

Comment: @AmirSarfar Unfortunately, there is nothing in the description on the link about the desired behavior.